# Jmeter is out of heap memory

Tags: java, performance, jmeter

I'm trying to run a performance test in multiple databases, reading the info from a csv file, but after a while the Jmeter failed the test cases, because it rans out of memory.

I tried to increased "java -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m  -Xms3072m -Xmx3072m -jar Apache-JMeter.jar" in this way but I having the same result.

Also Jmeter is creating a mysql connection to 5 different databases.

Comment: Which JDK you are using IBM or Oracle? I am a Java Service Engg. I could help you to get more details

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have a 64 bit operating system and JVM and lots of RAM available.

You can't guess about these things.  Better to get some data using a profiler.  Use something like dynaTrace, JProfiler or, if you have an Oracle JVM, the Visual VM tool that ships with the JVM.

You can't figure out what the problem is until you have some data.  Maybe you need to write your tests differently so you don't have so much data in memory all at once.

Answer (score 0):

first things first, are you modifying those command lines in the jmeter bat correct? because based on your dump we should be able to see how much ram you are ACTUALLY using..
e.g.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space Dumping heap to java_pid999999.hprof ... Heap dump file created [591747609 bytes in 1321.244 secs]  in this case this means that I was using a jmeter configured with a xmx of 591747609 bytes aka 512mb of ram.. 
By this we can understand if your settings are even being applied..

If that's fine, anyway post some profiler info and we'll see..
but consider these points:
1) jmeter in guimode is a real bottleneck if you want to see what's the performance of your java application... consider switching to remote testing.
2) check best practice on jmeter configuration, there are some sub-optimal settings in jmeter which hogs WAY too much memory, and you might want to turn them off...

give us an update and we'll see what advice can be given.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you

1. [Run JMeter in non-GUI mode](http://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)
2. Disable all listeners, especially [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) and [View Results in Table](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_in_Table) ones
3. Use CSV as results output format
4. Avoid queries producing large result sets
5. Use Post Processors and Assertions only when and where required
6. Use latest version of JMeter on 64-bit OS and using latest version of 64-bit JDK

If you still experience OOM errors you will need to either switch to machine having more RAM or consider [distributed testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html).